# Github Typescript --> Javascript diff comparison

Tags: javascript, typescript, github

While adding features and updating code in a file I like to simultaneously refactor the file from `.js` to `.ts`.

When looking at the pull request the final diffs show just the removed file and the added file, which makes a direct comparison of more highlighted code changes difficult. Even if the refactoring were done in a separate commit, latter changes to code would require multiple commit comparisons.

Is there a standard way (outside of IDEs like Webstorm, VScode etc) to compare refactors like this, TS-specific or otherwise, that might intuit the changes of note and allow for more streamlined reviews?

Hopefully this isn't a duplicate question, I couldn't seem to find one while searching.

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered `git mv` which is the solution to this problem.
`git mv path/to/file.js path/to/file.ts`
Now your diff will work!